How can I display a PPT file in Flutter?
I want to display a PPT file in my Flutter app. I'm receiving the PPT file URL from an API and need to display it.
Currently, I'm using a WebView to achieve this because I haven't found any Flutter packages that support PPT files directly, although there are packages available for displaying PDFs.
